# My chrome extension to inject css wont work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, javascript-framework

I am busy developing a chrome extension.

What it will do:

1. Get data from a PHP page (XMLHttpRequest)
2. Split the result variable using .split
3. And when someone clicks on a div, it will call a function to insert a css file with that name I got in number 1.

My problem:

Well nothing happens when I click that button. It works when I used the variable, "newvar", instead of the variable, "currenttheme" from the XMLHttpRequest. I tried converting it to a string as well using .toString. Oh, alerting the variable does work and gives exactly the same response as newvar.

My code: (Sigh!)

```
//My XMLHttpRequest
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    user_data = xmlhttp.responseText;
    window.user_data = user_data;
    processdata();
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8888/myphppage.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();

function processdata() {
//split result variable from PHP
var downdata = user_data.split('|||||');
var installedthemes = downdata[0];
currenttheme = downdata[1].toString();
window.currenttheme = currenttheme.toString();
}

function click(e) {
  newvar = "001";
  //insert css - works with variable newvar but not with this one
  chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null,
  {file:currenttheme + ".css"});
  //alerting the variable works, exactly the same as newvar
  alert (currenttheme);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('click', click);
  }
});
```

Comment: A better title to your question may help you get more responses.

Comment: Now *//code for IE6, IE5* is *really* defensive programming for a chrome extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.user_data = user_data;// <- not required. user_data = xmlhttp.responseText implies user_data is global to this window.
window.currenttheme = currenttheme.toString(); <<- not required too

also downdata[1] IS a string so replace

```
currenttheme = downdata[1].toString();
```

with

```
currenttheme = downdata[1];
```

If this doesn't help, try alert(currenttheme); and see if you are getting the required theme name, because sometimes PHP can throw errors and die which may not produce a "|||||". Check the php output and alert the xmlhttp.responseText too to see if everything is OK.

Comment: I did alert it. With or without the extra code it alerts correctly but wont work.

Comment: OK, quickly take a backup of the php file and in the PHP file, just add the following:
"|||||001" <<- that must be the only thing on the php file.
 .Save the file as the php file and run the page again and check if it works. Also CLEAR CACHE  time to time if these scripts are included in a seperate .js file.

Comment: Also try file:(currenttheme + ".css")

Comment: Using just "|||||001" worked perfectly! Why is that? Oh, adding ( and ) didn't help. Thanks!

Comment: I solved it! There were extra lines of code below the closing php tag, resulting in a second line. Couldn't have done it without you. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Could have helped you earlier. Just to post a quick fix - if you still need the extra lines of code after your php, prefix it with "|||||", so that it the remaining explodes to the 3rd array index, ie; downdata[2]. :)